# Kubernetes Service Object ExternalName pointing to Azure CDN

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, containers

My app is running on Windows Containers using AKS. Now we are trying to migrate our Static Assets to Azure Blob/Azure CDN and serve assets from there instead of our App. Following various articles, I setup the below way with no success.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-fe
  namespace: fe-ns
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name:app-fe
    helm.sh/chart: os-20210118.1
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: prod
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: fe-assets.azureedge.net
```

Ingress file

```
annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "domain.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: app-fe
              servicePort: 80/443 (tried with both)
```

Any leads on this is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you run curl app-fe.default:80 from any of the pods within the cluster and it reaches the url correctly. For https, you may need to provide TLS details I think

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this won't work because Kubernetes goes to CDN using IP address and not hostname. All CDNs will return you something like 503 in return because this is not how they're supposed to work.

Comment: So what is the best way to read static assets hosted in Azure blob from AKS?

Comment: so the suggestion is to configure my domain to point to Azure CDN and do api routing from Azure to send other requests to AKS.

Comment: does settingup a custom domain for CDN endpoint works??